# cocos2d position coordinate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

when i debug the following code, the xPos = 0, yPos = 0, weird

```
CCNode* node = [birdsAlone objectAtIndex:nextInactiveBird];
NSAssert([node isKindOfClass:[BirdEntity class]], @"not a bird entity");
BirdEntity* bird = (BirdEntity*) node;
float birdHeight = CGRectGetHeight([bird boundingBox]);
float xPos = ([[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width - 100) * CCRANDOM_0_1() + 50;
float yPos = ([[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].height + birdHeight / 2.0f);

CGPoint location = ccp(xPos, yPos);
```

Comment: what are the values of [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize] and birdHeight ?

Comment: not found in debugger. ok now. i use clang debug and analyze, turns out that the birdsAlone is nil and node is garbage...i use [CCArray arrayWithCapacity:20] instead of [[CCArray alloc] initWithCapacity], typed too fast^_^

Comment: Hey there, are you debugging in "debug" or in "release" mode ? You shouldn't get birdsAlone == nil ... also , please specify the function where this piece of code is placed in. is birdsAlone a class member ? an input parameter ?

Comment: i debug it in debugging mode. i don't think it's the code's issue. birdsAlone is an array of birds(since in this game mode, there are no fish.)

Answer (score 1):

When you get 0s where you don't expect them, two common causes are:

- Integer rounding.  For example, if you do int x = 3 * .25, x will be 0.  I don't think this is your problem.
- One of the objects in your chain is nil.  Remember, in Cocoa, [nil anySelector] is valid -- it doesn't crash with a nil object as you might expect.  [nil intValue] (or floatValue, etc.) == 0.  So if you have [[myObject someProperty] someOtherProperty], any of those things along the way being 0 will cause the result to be zero.